# implementing a deferred exception in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, exception

I would like to implement a deferred exception in Python that is OK to store somewhere but as soon as it is used in any way, it raises the exception that was deferred. Something like this:

```
# this doesn't work but it's a start
class DeferredException(object):
    def __init__(self, exc):
        self.exc = exc
    def __getattr__(self, key):
        raise self.exc

# example:

mydict = {'foo': 3}
try:
    myval = obtain_some_number()
except Exception as e:
    myval = DeferredException(e)
mydict['myval'] = myval

def plus_two(x):
    print x+2

# later on...
plus_two(mydict['foo'])     # prints 5
we_dont_use_this_val = mydict['myval']   # Always ok to store this value if not used

plus_two(mydict['myval'])   # If obtain_some_number() failed earlier, 
                            # re-raises the exception, otherwise prints the value + 2.
```

The use case is that I want to write code to analyze some values from incoming data; if this code fails but the results are never used, I want it to fail quietly; if it fails but the results are used later, then I'd like the failure to propagate.

Any suggestions on how to do this? If I use my DeferredException class I get this result:

```
>>> ke = KeyError('something')
>>> de = DeferredException(ke)
>>> de.bang                                   # yay, this works
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 6, in __getattr__
KeyError: 'something'
>>> de+2                                      # boo, this doesn't
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'DeferredException' and 'int'
```

Comment: I suppose your function could return a function that either generates the values or raises an error, but otherwise I don't see how you could do this.

Comment: Well, you could overload *all* the special functions (`__add__`, `__call__`, etc.)... I'm not sure I like this deferred exception idea, though -- surely it's unexpected for exceptions to be thrown in harmless-looking code far removed from where the actual error occurred?

Comment: Why not maintain state / use `finally` blocks instead of trying to do something magical ..

Comment: wim -- because it's a framework that exists and needs a slight tweak. Yeah, I'd rewrite it if I could, but I need to handle this minor case, and I don't have resources for a full rewrite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read section 3.4.12 of the docs, "Special method lookup for new-style classes."  It explains exactly the problem you have encountered.  The normal attribute lookup is bypassed by the interpreter for certain operators, such as addition (as you found out the hard way).  Thus the statement de+2 in your code never calls your **getattr** function.

The only solution, according to that section, is to insure that "the special method must be set on the class object itself in order to be consistently invoked by the interpreter."

Perhaps you'd be better off storing all your deferred exceptions in a global list, wrapping your entire program in a try:finally: statement, and printing out the whole list in the finally block.

Comment: So a quick-n-dirty solution for python-2.7 is to switch to the old-style `class DeferredException:`. Per 3.4.11, the lookup is always performed in this case, and `de+2` will behave as desired.

Comment: The operative words there are "quick and dirty" since that solution would be incompatible with Python 3.  But if it solves your immediate problem, so be it.